# ¿Cómo mostrar los datos de una variable que ocupo dentro de un $.each fuera de este?

Tags: jquery

Mi pregunta es sencilla, cómo mostrar los datos de una variable que ocupo dentro de un **each** fuera de este con **jquery**?

```
$.each( data_json, function(index, valores ) {  
  var c = valores.objeto_elegido;
});
console.log(c);
```

Comment: Podrias agregar el código del cual nace tu pregunta para poderte ayudar mejor.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es para nada clara y puede llegar a ser cerrada, intenta dar una mejor explicación para que podamos ayudarte de una mejor manera.

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/63725/edit).

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo del resultado esperado? Porque a priori eso no está claro, es decir, la variable `c` a medida que se recorre el arreglo/ objeto, tendrá múltiples valores y al finalizar la iteración el valor será igual al último elemento/propiedad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que lo que quieres es hacer un `$.each` a un Array u Object, definir una variable dentro del ciclo $.each, y usar esa variable fuera del ciclo.

Este es el escenario "normal":

```
var myArray = [ ... ]; // Este es el array sobre el que correrás el $.each
$.each(myArray, function(){
   var test = true; // Aquí defines la variable que quieres usar después
});
console.log(test); // Da error: variable no definida
```

La variable fue definida dentro del ciclo, por lo que no existe fuera de este y da un error al tratar de usarla. Se dice que la variable pertenece al ámbito (*scope*) de esa función.

La solución es definirla fuera del ciclo, con lo que queda dentro del ámbito *global* y puedes usarla desde dentro de la función:

```
var myArray = [ ... ]; // Este es el array sobre el que correrás el $.each
var test; // Esta es la variable que vas a modificar dentro del ciclo $.each
$.each(myArray, function(){
   // Aquí modificas el valor de la variable. Ojo que no se debe usar "var"
   test = true; 
});
console.log(test); // Se muestra el valor de la variable
```

Comment: Esto me resultó, muchas gracias. Lo estaba haciendo mal tenia 2 each y colocaba esa variable dentro del each que estaba mas afuera pero colocandolo fuera de los 2 resultó.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto es lo que buscas amigo

```js
$json= [{'nombre':'pedro','edad':15},{'nombre':'juan','edad':15}];
$datos = [];
$.each($json,function(index,valores){
    var c = valores.nombre;
    $datos.push(c);
});
console.log($datos);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```